# Adding results to a dictionary using xelement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

```
private Dictionary<int, double> TaxDiction { set; get; }     

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(path);
var query = from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
            where (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id") == empID
            select new AllowancePaid
            {
                TaxDiction = ??
            };
var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

*Edited*
I am selecting from an xml file and would like to insert the values into a dictionary (TaxDiction). before I would select the two values and insert it into separate list as shown below:

```
list1 = nm.Element("ListOfTaxableAllowance").Elements("Amount").Attributes("BenListId").Select(a => (int)a).ToList(),
list2 = nm.Element("ListOfTaxableAllowance").Elements("Amount").Select(a => (double)a).ToList()
```

However the values from the two list are related and i would like to insert them into a dictionary. so the values in list1 will be the keys and the values from list2 will my the values in my dictionary. I thought it would be more efficient like this as the values are related. I hope this help to clear things up a little. thank you.

EDITED

I tried....

```
TaxDiction.Add(nm.Element("ListOfTaxableAllowance").Elements("Amount").Attributes("BenListId").Select(a => (int)a).ToList(),nm.Element("ListOfTaxableAllowance").Elements("Amount").Attributes("BenListId").Select(a => (int)a).ToList())
```

However i got an invalid initializer member declarator

XML Sample file.

```
  <EmployeeFinance>
    <EmpPersonal_Id>494</EmpPersonal_Id>
    <NonStatDedct>
      <DeductedAmt NonStatID="1037">0</DeductedAmt>
      <DeductedAmt NonStatID="106">5000</DeductedAmt>
    </NonStatDedct>
    <TotalDeduction>39909.83</TotalDeduction>
    <TotalTaxableEarnings>120054.27</TotalTaxableEarnings>
    <TotalNonTaxableEarnings>29500</TotalNonTaxableEarnings>
    <No_DaysWorked>21.667</No_DaysWorked>
    <Payperiod_EndDate>2014-02-28T00:00:00</Payperiod_EndDate>
    <Exchange_Rate>207.00</Exchange_Rate>
    <Currency>GYD</Currency>
    <Date_Appointment>2009-11-30T00:00:00</Date_Appointment>
    <Date_Employment>1994-12-01T00:00:00</Date_Employment>
    <Date_Termination>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Date_Termination>
    <Payperiod_StartDate>2014-02-01T00:00:00</Payperiod_StartDate>
    <BatchNumber>3192</BatchNumber>
    <PAYE_Free_Pay_Awarded>50000</PAYE_Free_Pay_Awarded>
    <Income_Tax_RateID>4</Income_Tax_RateID>
    <NIS_RateID>1</NIS_RateID>
    <Daily_Rate>5540.881</Daily_Rate>
    <NIS_weeks_worked>0</NIS_weeks_worked>
    <Incentive />
    <Retro>0</Retro>
    <ListOfTaxableAllowance>
      <Amount BenListId="4">0.00000</Amount>
      <Amount BenListId="0">0</Amount>
    </ListOfTaxableAllowance>
    <ListOfTNonaxableAllowance>
      <Amount BenListId="4">23500.00000</Amount>
      <Amount BenListId="0">0</Amount>
    </ListOfTNonaxableAllowance>
    <ListOfTaxableBenefits>
      <Amount BenListID="0">0</Amount>
    </ListOfTaxableBenefits>
    <ListOfNonTaxableBenefits>
      <Amount BenListID="0">0</Amount>
    </ListOfNonTaxableBenefits>
    <ListOfTaxableAddIncome>
      <Amount AddEarnID="14">0.00000</Amount>
    </ListOfTaxableAddIncome>
    <ListOfNonTaxableAddIncome>
      <Amount AddEarnID="14">6000.00000</Amount>
    </ListOfNonTaxableAddIncome>
    <ListOfNISdeductible>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
    </ListOfNISdeductible>
    <ListOfOtherTaxableAmount>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
    </ListOfOtherTaxableAmount>
    <ListOfPartofPension>
      <Amount>23500.00</Amount>
    </ListOfPartofPension>
  </EmployeeFinance>
```

Comment: What problem you have with your current attempt? Parsing exception? Why you have two exactly same lines of code? Where is sample xml?

Comment: I made an edit above.. reading from the xml is fine. i can select an insert it into a list however i think it would be more efficient if i can insert it into a dictionary. I dont know how to insert it into a dictionary. Inserting into a list works!

Comment: if you continue reading you will see .. EDITED .. and i show the attempt i made.. please read the entire problem first before commenting.

Comment: @Maverick1415 your question is not clear.You are trying to select exactly same values (it's wrong and doesn't compile) but still you didn't explain your problem clearly and didn't show us the xml file format.how can we help you if you didn't provide us enough information?

Comment: @Maverick1415 what data from this file you want in dictionary?

Comment: I added the sample xml.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i will edit the file and try to be clearer. sorry for this.

Comment: @Maverick1415 that does not explain *what* you want to select. You just show *how* you try to do that

Comment: @Maverick1415 other notes - there is no `EmpPersonal_Id` element. Also there is single `EmployeeFinance` which is root

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy .. sorry .. i didnt copy it over. I edited the question. can you please re-read and hopefully it makes things clearer. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need dictionary with `BenListId` attribute as key, and `Amount` as value:

```
TaxDiction = nm.Element("ListOfTaxableAllowance")
               .Elements("Amount")
               .ToDictionary(a => (int)a.Attribute("BenListId"),
                             a => (double)a)
```

Comment: Wow .. thank you.. this is exactly what i needed. sorry for the mix up.. beautiful!

Comment: @Maverick1415 it would be lot more easier to find the solution if you state your requirement in simple English with brevity i.e. what you are trying to achieve first,then what you have tried so far with some sample code. Good luck!